# Tabbed content not appearing on orientation

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have 2 tabs that both display a jQuery slider - flexslider (this is a mobile site). In portrait mode there are 2 images (so 2 divs) and in landscape mode there are 3 images (so 3 divs). They're held in different container code, that's controlled by CSS as to which appears based on the orientation. Problem is the first tab displays fine as the device picks up the orientation, but when you toggle to the other tab the content doesn't appear, testing this in normal desktop browser it does appear as soon as the window is ever so slightly resized. Here's the code in a nutshell:

```
HTML:

    <!--tabs-->
    <div id="toggleLeft" class="active toggleBox"><a href="" >New Promotions</a></div>
    <div id="toggleRight" class="toggleBox"><a href="">Ending soon</a></div>

    <!--containers-->

    <div id="toggleBoxLeft">
      <div id="mainPortrait" role="main">SLIDER CODE FOR PORTRAIT VIEW</div>
      <div id="mainLandscape" role="main">SLIDER CODE FOR LANDSCAPE VIEW</div>
    </div>

    <div id="toggleBoxRight">
      <div id="mainPortrait2" role="main">SLIDER CODE FOR PORTRAIT VIEW</div>
      <div id="mainLandscape2" role="main">SLIDER CODE FOR LANDSCAPE VIEW</div>
    </div>

    CSS:

    @media all and (orientation:landscape){

    #mainPortrait           {
        margin-left: 0px; 
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    #mainLandscape          {
        margin-left: 0px; 
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility:visible;
    }

    #mainPortrait2          {
        margin-left: 0px; 
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    #mainLandscape2             {
        margin-left: 0px; 
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility:visible;
    }

    }
```

How do I "force" the browser to load both tabs content even though the CSS is declaring at `display:none;`?